# Parsing JSON Tableview Information as Separate Strings

Tags: ios, json, swift, string, uitableview

I am currently trying to use information in Tableview cells that I have populated with JSON to execute various operations but I am unable to call the specific information due to the fact that it isn't in individual strings. Is there any way to take the group of data I have pulled into each tableview cell and turn it into a series of individual strings? Here is what I currently have:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class OngoingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var userUsernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var ongoingTable: UITableView!

    var list:[MyStruct] = [MyStruct]()

    struct MyStruct
    {
        var user1 = ""
        var user2 = ""
        var wager = ""
        var amount = ""

        init(_ user1:String, _ user2:String, _ wager:String, _ amount:String)
        {
            self.user1 = user1
            self.user2 = user2
            self.wager = wager
            self.amount = amount
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userUsername")!
        userUsernameLabel.text = username


        /// The banner view.
        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())


        ongoingTable.dataSource = self
        ongoingTable.delegate = self

        get_data("http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team10/ongoingWagers.php")
    }


    func get_data(_ link:String)
    {
        let url:URL = URL(string: link)!


        var request = URLRequest(url:url);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";


        let postString = "a=\(userUsernameLabel.text!)";


        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in



            self.extract_data(data)

        }

        task.resume()
    }


    func extract_data(_ data:Data?)
    {
        let json:Any?

        if(data == nil)
        {
            return
        }

        do{
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let data_array = json as? NSArray else
        {
            return
        }


        for i in 0 ..< data_array.count
        {
            if let data_object = data_array[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let data_user1 = data_object["id"] as? String,
                    let data_user2 = data_object["id2"] as? String,
                    let data_wager = data_object["wager"] as? String,
                    let data_amount = data_object["amount"] as? String
                {
                    list.append(MyStruct(data_user1, data_user2, data_wager, data_amount))
                }

            }
        }


        refresh_now()


    }

    func refresh_now()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(
            execute:
            {
                self.ongoingTable.reloadData()

        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.ongoingTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "owcell", for: indexPath) as! OngoingTableViewCell

        cell.infoLabel.text = list[indexPath.row].user1 + " " +  list[indexPath.row].user2 + " " + list[indexPath.row].wager + " " + list[indexPath.row].amount

        cell.user1Button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.user1Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OngoingViewController.user1Action), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.user2Button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.user2Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OngoingViewController.user2Action), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell

    }


    @IBAction func user1Action(sender: UIButton) {

        let user1Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wait a second!", message: "Are you sure this user has won this wager?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        user1Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

            let user1ConfirmationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Great!", message: "Please wait for the other user to confirm the winner of this wager.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            user1ConfirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(user1ConfirmationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
        user1Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(user1Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func user2Action(sender: UIButton) {

        let user2Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wait a second!", message: "Are you sure this user has won this wager?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        user2Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

            let user2ConfirmationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Great!", message: "Please wait for the other user to confirm the winner of this wager.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            user2ConfirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(user2ConfirmationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
        user2Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(user2Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

Here is the OngoingTableViewCell subclass:

```
import UIKit

class OngoingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var user1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var user2Button: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "series of individual strings"?

Comment: So this JSON is inserting "user1, user2, wager, amount". I want to be able to chop those up individually so I can perform operations on them after they've been inserted into the the tableview cells. If that makes sense...For example, I want to include "user1" in a conditional statement but I am unable to since it isn't its own string.

Comment: So you for example want to access user from the clicked row in `user1Action` method?

Comment: I want the user1Action to take information from the tableview cell and compare it to the userDefault.

Comment: I just need to find a way to isolate that user from the JSON array that populates the tableview cell

Comment: So why not override `UITableViewCell`, add data to it at implement the user1Action inside this overriden class?

Comment: Could you explain that further? Sorry I am relatively new to this

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't notice that you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass. Can you also show the code of your `OngoingTableViewCell`?

Comment: So move the `user1Action` and `user2Action` to the OngoingTableViewCell and also give it the proper `MyStruct` instance as a property.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of MyStruct structures, that contain entries for user1, user1, wager, and amount. That's good.

You're using tags on the buttons as a way of figuring out the selected cell, which is not ideal. Instead I would suggest using the sender parameter to figure out the indexPath of the cell that contains the button. See the bottom of my answer for the details of a better way to do it.

In any case, once you have a row number, you can easily get to the data for that wager by indexing into your array:

```
@IBAction func user1Action(sender: UIButton) {

  selectedRow = sender.tag
  //or, using my function:
  selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForView(sender)

  //Get the wager for the button the user tapped on.
  let thisWager = list[selectedRow]
}
```

If you want to take action on the wager once the user taps a button in your `UIAlertController`, don't use a nil handler on the your second alert controller. Instead, pass in a closure that uses the `selectedRow` parameter from the code above to index into the list of wagers, or even use the `thisWager` local variable I show in my code.

---

### Getting the indexPath of the button the user taps on:

---

I created a simple extension to UITableView that lets you pass in a UIView (like the sender from a button action) and get back the indexPath that contains that view.

That extension is dirt-simple. Here's how it looks:

```
public extension UITableView {
  
  /**
  This method returns the indexPath of the cell that contains the specified view
   - Parameter view: The view to find.
   - Returns: The indexPath of the cell containing the view, or nil if it can't be found
  */
  
  func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
    let origin = view.bounds.origin
    let viewOrigin = self.convert(origin, from: view)
    let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewOrigin)
    return indexPath
  }
}
```

And you can call that function from your button's actions:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForView(button) {
    print("Button tapped at indexPath \(indexPath)")
  }
  else {
    print("Button indexPath not found")
  }
}
```

The whole project can be found on Github at this link: [**TableViewExtension**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/TableViewExtension)